# Как узнать конфигурацию компьютера с помощью pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Может кто сталкивался с проблемой получения информации о рабочем окружении пользователей?

Comment: Вы хотите знать, как на сервере узнать, что творится у клиента? Только если клиент сам предоставит такую информацию. Удобный интерфейс со стороны СУБД для этого есть, но выбор "пользоваться им или нет" остается за клиентом.

Comment: ага) а не подскажите какой интерфейс со стороны СУБД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со стороны СУБД есть пакет `dbms_application_info` (подробности в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003)) и системное вью `v$session` ([V$SESSION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9.htm#REFRN30223)). Во вью есть поля `PROGRAM`, `MODULE`, `ACTION`и `CLIENT_INFO`, содержание которых вы можете посмотреть на сервере. Заполнить их можно с клиента, вызвав соответствующую процедуру из пакета `dbms_application_info`. Соответственно, вы можете увидеть там всё, что сможет и захочет поместить туда разработчик клиентского приложения. Плюс есть еще несколько полей с IP-адресом, названием машины и т. п.

Comment: Большое спасибо)